# How to add extra time into the time column with data using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have a dataset with date, time and one input column. So here my time column is not good. So I want to give time range into that time column. So here first I did I just convert start time into 0 and convert whole time column into minutes.

Then next what I want to give time range like `0,60,120....`

Mean what I expected output is:

first time convert

```html
date      time         time          
10/3/2018 6:15:00       0              
10/3/2018 6:45:00       30             
10/3/2018 7:45:00       90              
10/3/2018 9:00:00       165.0           
10/3/2018 9:25:00       190.0           
10/3/2018 9:30:00       195.0            
10/3/2018 11:00:00      285.0
10/3/2018 11:30:00      315.0
```

Expected output

```html
time            x3
0               7
30              5
60              0
120             0
165             7
180             0
190             7
195             5
240             0
285             7
300             0
315             7
```

So here you can see extra time added `60,120,180...`  for that x3 values are not available Then add `0` into x3 column

So here I just want to do is `extra 60 min 60 min add to the time column`

Here I wrote the code for convert time. But I don't know how to fill the extra 60 min into the time column.

My code:

```
data['date']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                    format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)

lastday = data.loc[0, 'date']
def convert_time(x):
global lastday
if x.date() == lastday.date():
    tm = x - lastday
    return tm.total_seconds()/60
else:
    lastday = x
    return 0

data['time'] = data['date'].apply(convert_time)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Subset of my csv:

```html
date time X3
10/3/2018 6:15:00 7
10/3/2018 6:45:00 5
10/3/2018 7:45:00 7
10/3/2018 9:00:00 7
10/3/2018 9:25:00 7
10/3/2018 9:30:00 5
10/3/2018 11:00:00 7
10/3/2018 11:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:30:00 7
10/3/2018 13:50:00 5
10/3/2018 15:00:00 7
10/3/2018 15:25:00 7
10/3/2018 16:25:00 7
10/3/2018 18:00:00 7
10/3/2018 19:00:00 5
```

My csv :
[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dR1wa5kNlwXz3VYvpNmBUZDCu_2iZ8opgh_eSj_E9-c/edit#gid=0)

for the reference:

```html
                   expected time                            
                         0.0
                         30.0             
                         60
                         90.0 
                         120
                         165.0
                         180
                         190.0
                         195.0
                         240
                         285.0
                         300
                         315.0
                         360
                         420
                         435
                         455
                         480
                         525
                         540
                         550
                          :
                          :
                          :
                          :
                          0   new date ,start time=0
                          2
                          47
                          60
                          120
                          152
                          180
```

Comment: I check it now and time column is changed in output data? Because input data has 8 rows and output 6 rows.

Comment: @jezrael I edited my question. Now you can see my output is more than inputs. Because I added extra time into it. Then X3 column value will be 0 related to that extra time.

Comment: @jezrael I just want to add extra 60 min into my time column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
data['date']= pd.to_datetime(data['date'] + " " + data['time'],
                    format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', dayfirst=True)
```

Subtract firat value of date column and convert to minutes:

```
data['time1'] = data['date'].sub(data.loc[0, 'date']).dt.total_seconds()/60
print (data)
                  date      time  X3  time1
0  2018-03-10 06:15:00   6:15:00   7    0.0
1  2018-03-10 06:45:00   6:45:00   5   30.0
2  2018-03-10 07:45:00   7:45:00   7   90.0
3  2018-03-10 09:00:00   9:00:00   7  165.0
4  2018-03-10 09:25:00   9:25:00   7  190.0
5  2018-03-10 09:30:00   9:30:00   5  195.0
6  2018-03-10 11:00:00  11:00:00   7  285.0
7  2018-03-10 11:30:00  11:30:00   7  315.0
8  2018-03-10 13:30:00  13:30:00   7  435.0
9  2018-03-10 13:50:00  13:50:00   5  455.0
10 2018-03-10 15:00:00  15:00:00   7  525.0
11 2018-03-10 15:25:00  15:25:00   7  550.0
12 2018-03-10 16:25:00  16:25:00   7  610.0
13 2018-03-10 18:00:00  18:00:00   7  705.0
14 2018-03-10 19:00:00  19:00:00   5  765.0
```

Create new `60` range values:

```
arr = np.arange(0, int(data['time1'].max()), 60)
print (arr)
[  0  60 120 180 240 300 360 420 480 540 600 660 720]
```

Join together with minute column:

```
union = np.union1d(data['time1'], arr)
print (union)
[  0.  30.  60.  90. 120. 165. 180. 190. 195. 240. 285. 300. 315. 360.
 420. 435. 455. 480. 525. 540. 550. 600. 610. 660. 705. 720. 765.]
```

Create index by `time1` column and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - added new values from `arr`:

```
data = data.set_index('time1')['X3'].reindex(union, fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (data)
    time1  X3
0     0.0   7
1    30.0   5
2    60.0   0
3    90.0   7
4   120.0   0
5   165.0   7
6   180.0   0
7   190.0   7
8   195.0   5
9   240.0   0
10  285.0   7
11  300.0   0
12  315.0   7
13  360.0   0
14  420.0   0
15  435.0   7
16  455.0   5
17  480.0   0
18  525.0   7
19  540.0   0
20  550.0   7
21  600.0   0
22  610.0   7
23  660.0   0
24  705.0   7
25  720.0   0
26  765.0   5
```

Comment: Ohh thankyou friend. You saved my day . I have one question If I had inputs columns more than 1 , then how to add it into this code.\

Comment: @team - it is possible by `data = data.set_index('time1').reindex(union, fill_value=0).reset_index()` - but then get 0 for all columns - e.g. for datetimes default `'zero'` datetime `1970-01-01 00:00:00` and also for times `0`

Comment: worked it charm. Sorry to ask like this did you check my last question"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971667/how-to-add-this-summation-equation-inside-of-the-for-loop-function-with-timedelt" Can you have any idea to solve this process? Can you give me suggestion for this? Then I can also try it.

Comment: @ jezrael related to this question. Here one issue came , Here when the date is changed then the all the start time should be 0 and then again start to run 60 min. In your code it didn't came

Comment: @team - It is more complicated, because need this solution per groups - Is possible create new question with link to this question with specifying per groups by `2018-03-10`, `2018-03-11` ?

Comment: @ jezrael  sure I will. Here  I edited the question and you can see the reference

Comment: Hay friend I asked the new question. here is my link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57989459/cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-while-adding-extra-time"